# React Native: await is a reserved word

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to save the fact that my user is logged-in and then redirect him on his administration page but when I use await I got this error:

> await is a reserved word (101)

Another thing, once my user is registered I would like to send him to a new page, not a "slide page" where we can get back with the arrow on the top right-hand side. 
How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
 login(){
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailLogin, 
    this.state.passwordLogin).then((user) =>  {
        // Send the user to the next step
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like 
            to save it.');
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
        }
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; 
        navigate('Admin');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
            alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
            alert(errorMessage);         
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `await` in a function it must be marked as `async`

```
 this.state.passwordLogin).then( aysnc (user) =>  {
 ...
 })
```